# How to edit Mailchimp newsletter popup so it doesn't show up at certain pages?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, mailchimp

On my Avada Woocommerce shop I have a Mailchimp newsletter subscribe popup. It works great, but I don't want to have it showing up at every page.

I have tried to ad if(!is_home () ) to the Mailchimp code, but then the popup doesn't show up at all. This was the code I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"> if(!is_front_page()</script><script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us8.list-manage.com","uuid":"9f980694c46c2f3f935b4dfde","lid":"749912d7dc"}) }) if(!is_home()</script>
```

Any idea or tips and tricks how to exclude the popup from the homepage and shoppingcart/ and checkout pages? (I don't want to bother people who click on an abandon cart email with the popup).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are using is_front_page() in a wrong place.

Try using this

```
<?php if(!is_front_page() || !is_home()){?>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us8.list-manage.com","uuid":"9f980694c46c2f3f935b4dfde","lid":"749912d7dc"}) })
  </script>
<?php }?>
```

The above code works other than homepage, You need to add ids of the shopping cart and checkout to if condition if you dont want to display it for those two pages.

Lets take if your shopping cart page id is '123', then use this

```
<?php if(!is_front_page() || !is_home() || is_page('123')){?>
```

same like this for checkout too.

Comment: I have implemented the code in header.php but after that, the page won't scroll anymore. When I add the code in footer.php, the popup showsup anyway... Where to put it?